# evaluate matrix expression at points in a grid using Julia

Tags: matrix, julia

I had a small bit of (perhaps inefficient) Matlab code that generated a matrix of values of a function of the product of grid grid points.  For example:

```
N = 2 ;
r = -N:N ;
[X1, X2] = ndgrid( r, r ) ;
f = @( x ) ( x ) ; % identity: dummy function for this example.
X1
X2
f( X1 .* X2 )
```

producing:

```
X1 =

    -2    -2    -2    -2    -2
    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     2


X2 =

    -2    -1     0     1     2
    -2    -1     0     1     2
    -2    -1     0     1     2
    -2    -1     0     1     2
    -2    -1     0     1     2


ans =

     4     2     0    -2    -4
     2     1     0    -1    -2
     0     0     0     0     0
    -2    -1     0     1     2
    -4    -2     0     2     4
```

This was based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20388887/189270), and this Matlab [Evaluate Function over gridded domain help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) text.

I can implement this in Julia with a set of loops over the grid locations:

```
N = 2 ;
r = -N:N ;
twoNplusOne = 2*N + 1 ;

F = zeros( twoNplusOne, twoNplusOne ) ;
f = identity ; #say
for n = 1:twoNplusOne
   for m = 1:twoNplusOne
       F[ n, m ] = f( r[n]*r[m] ) ;
   end
end

F
```

... but was wondering if there's a more natural (and efficient) way to do this in Julia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it's the canonical Julian approach, but you could use `broadcast`:

```
julia> broadcast((x,y)->f(x*y), -N:N, (-N:N)')
5x5 Array{Int32,2}:
  4   2  0  -2  -4
  2   1  0  -1  -2
  0   0  0   0   0
 -2  -1  0   1   2
 -4  -2  0   2   4
```

where I've used `'` to turn the range from one of size `(5,)` to one of `(1,5)`.  Actually, in this particular case, since the function accepts a scalar argument and only depends on the product of your X1 and X2, we could even get away with

```
julia> f((-N:N) .* (-N:N)')
5x5 Array{Int32,2}:
  4   2  0  -2  -4
  2   1  0  -1  -2
  0   0  0   0   0
 -2  -1  0   1   2
 -4  -2  0   2   4
```

but that needn't be true in general.

Comment: I am pretty sure that's the canonical approach :-)

Answer (score 3):

The correct way would be to use a list/matrix comprehension:

```
[i*j for i in -2:2, j in -2:2]
```

or for a more general function

```
f(x,y) = x*y
[f(i,j) for i in -2:2, j in -2:2]
```